# How to select a class member using templates

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Consider the example code below.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

enum class FruitType {
    APPLE,
    ORANGE
};

class Fruit {
    uint64_t apple_count;
    uint64_t orange_count;

public:
    Fruit() : apple_count(0), orange_count(0) {}
    void increase_count(FruitType type) {
        if (type == FruitType::APPLE)
            apple_count++;
        else
            orange_count++;
    }
    void print() {
        std::cout << "apple_count: " << apple_count << std::endl;
        std::cout << "orange_count: " << orange_count << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int, char**) {
    Fruit fruit;
    fruit.increase_count(FruitType::APPLE);
    fruit.increase_count(FruitType::ORANGE);
    fruit.increase_count(FruitType::APPLE);
    fruit.increase_count(FruitType::APPLE);
    fruit.increase_count(FruitType::ORANGE);
    fruit.print();

    return 0;
}
```

I want the `increase_count` function to effectively compile to `increase_count_apple` and `increase_count_orange`. This is a simplified example of another class where such compile-time optimisation helps me at runtime, in theory. Intuitively, this feels possible using templates, but I am unable to arrive at a satisfactory output.

Comment: whats wrong with the code you have? or the alternative of calling `increase_count_apple` and `increase_count_orange` in `main` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number There are other libraries which will use this class, and they may choose to only use apple or orange, and I want to optimise for the other half not being compiled at all.

Comment: Note that the code you have removes all the calls to `increase_count`  even at `-O1` and boils down to `std::cout << "apple_count: " << 3 << std::endl; std::cout << "orange_count: " << 2 << std::endl;`: https://godbolt.org/z/c9oqo9sjx. It may be worth checking if your real example is also optimised before you do any refactoring.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen In this case all the code is in the TU so it is trivial for the compiler to optimize.  If `Fruit` is defined in it's own TU like it should be then it is much less likely to be optimized away.,

Comment: You may make increase_count template on ```FruitType``` and use SFINAE to select the right implem (before C++17) or use ```if constexpr``` (from C++17). Then the call site can be: ```fruit.increase_count<FruitType::APPLE>();```.
Is it what you want to achieve?
Does your real problem implies that ```Fruit``` knows, at compile-time, all managed *fruits*?

Comment: NathanOliver has just post an example illustrating my precedent comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By making `increase_count` a template that takes a non-type template paramter you can do

```
class Fruit {
    uint64_t apple_count;
    uint64_t orange_count;

public:
    Fruit() : apple_count(0), orange_count(0) {}
    template <FruitType type>
    void increase_count() {
        if constexpr (type == FruitType::APPLE)
            apple_count++;
        else
            orange_count++;
    }
    void print() {
        std::cout << "apple_count: " << apple_count << std::endl;
        std::cout << "orange_count: " << orange_count << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int, char**) {
    Fruit fruit;
    fruit.increase_count<FruitType::APPLE>();
    fruit.increase_count<FruitType::ORANGE>();
    fruit.increase_count<FruitType::APPLE>();
    fruit.increase_count<FruitType::APPLE>();
    fruit.increase_count<FruitType::ORANGE>();
    fruit.print();

    return 0;
}
```

which removes the branch at compile time and `fruit.increase_count<FruitType::APPLE>` effectively calls `increase_count_apple` and `fruit.increase_count<FruitType::ORANGE>()` calls `increase_count_orange`.